# How can I set user range input boxes in these two lines?

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that matches 3 or more job skills to a huge data set and spits out jobs in other areas of the company where those skills are transferrable. Code works phenomenally, but I'd like to incorporate user input boxes for two lines of code.

1. `Set rSkills = Range("A2:A7")` I would want the user to select the range in column A from row 2 to the last job skill inputted.
2. `If i >= 3 Then` I also want an input box to show up and have the user type how many of the job skills they want to match each job. If they only need 1, I would want the input box to allow a 1 to be typed in, or more if needed.

How can this be achieved? Here is all of my code:

```
Sub FindSkills()

Dim c As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim row As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim rSkills As Range
Dim cSkills As Range
Dim JobCodeMatch As Integer
Dim JobTitleMatch As Integer
Dim CLevelMatch As Integer
Dim JobCode As String
Dim JobTitle As String
Dim CareerLevel As String

    row = 2
    JobCodeMatch = 2
    JobTitleMatch = 2
    CLevelMatch = 2

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set rSkills = Range("A2:A7")
    Do While row < 2400 
      i = 0 'reset
      JobCode = Cells(row, 6).Value
      JobTitle = Cells(row, 7).Value
      CareerLevel = Cells(row, 14).Value

      Set r = Range(Cells(row, 6), Cells(row, 336))
      For Each c In r
        For Each cSkills In rSkills
          If c.Value = cSkills.Value Then i = i + 1
        Next cSkills
      Next c
      If i >= 2 Then
        Cells(JobCodeMatch, 3) = JobCode 'Column C
        Cells(JobTitleMatch, 4) = JobTitle 'Column D
        Cells(CLevelMatch, 5) = CareerLevel
        JobCodeMatch = JobCodeMatch + 1
        JobTitleMatch = JobTitleMatch + 1
        CLevelMatch = CLevelMatch + 1
      End If
      row = row + 1
    Loop

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I would use a User Form with a ComboBox and not an input box for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Have you tried `inputbox`? or as suggested a userform with text box for the number of jobs and a `refEdit` for the range.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, I got the input range in column A to work with: 

    `Set rSkills = Application.Selection`

    `Set rSkills = Application.InputBox("Select Job Competencies in Column A", TitleID, rSkills.Address, Type:=8)`
    

but I also just need something like that for `i`, I don't feel that it's necessary to go through a whole user input form combo box for literally just one more variable that requires user input?